# What's the best way to "wrap up" HTML with a User Control?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I currently have this block of code (or something similiar) on almost all my pages:

```
<div class="tasks">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Do something</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Do something else</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

However, I need to turn this into a user control. I'd like something that looks like the following:

```
<foo:TaskList id="foo" runat="server">
    <Task><a href="#">Do something</a></Task>
    <Task><a href="#">Do something else</a></Task>
</foo:TaskList>
```

or even:

```
<foo:TaskList id="foo" runat="server">
   <Tasks>
       <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Do something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Do something else</a></li>
       </ul>
   </Tasks>
</foo:TaskList>
```

I realise that I'm using the "Template" concept there and I also realise that that's not how you're meant to use Template user controls. So.. how *am* I meant to wrap up a variable piece of HTML into a User Control?

PS. I don't want to use DataBinding or code-behind to populate this control. All the items must be visible in the ASPX file.

Comment: ...you mean you want the items to be visible in the Designer of Visual Studio?  Why?

Comment: I hadn't really though about the designer.. I just want to be able to see them in the ASPX code.

Answer (score 1):

Look at below these class can give you the below markup in your .aspx pages.  You can keep on going deeper.  All you need to have is a property on the parent object.  So it is pretty simple to achieve.

```
<Test:TestUserControl>
    <Tasks>
        <Test:Task Value="Some Value" Text="Some Text" />
        <Test:Task Value="Another Value" Text="More Text" />
    </Tasks>
</Test:TestUserControl>

namespace TestWebControls
{
    public class TestUserControl : WebControl
    {

        private List<Task> _Tasks;

        [NotifyParentProperty(true)]
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public List<Task> Tasks
        {
            get
            {
                return _Tasks;
            }
            set
            {
                _Tasks = value;
            }
        }

        public TestUserControl()
        {

        }
    }

    public class Task : WebControl
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now there is more work to be done when it comes to rendering.  So look up [Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302038.aspx) in ASP.NET and you will be able to finish the rest.  You would have to create a designer so the controls can be seen at design time.  And then a way to render them.

Comment: That's interesting, thank you. Can the same thing be achieved with a User Control? (And is there any advantage in that?)

Comment: Well it is a user control but instead of doing it with a designer we do it with C# code.  I haven't really tried it with a user control.  I am not sure you could, since it needs that List<> or array to put the sub items into it.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you have the same piece of HTML code on many pages, then you might also want to check out master pages.

A master page allows you to define a common "page frame" that can be reused by several (content-) pages.

(but maybe this suggestion is completely inappropriate, since you probably already know about masterpages).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass parameters to UserControls inside the HTML source.

You need to set the parameters in the page's Page_Load event:

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public void SetTasks(Tasks[] tasks)
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

and in the page source code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myUserControl.SetTasks(... tasks ...);
}
```